# Started Service in Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-service

i am trying to initiate a service from a tab, i have created the buttons in onCreateView method but i startService method doesn't seem to appear anywhere

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {




   final Button startServiceButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.strtserviceBtn);

   startServiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MyService.class);
           startService(intent);

       }
   });

    return view;

}
```

The startService just tries to create another method of this name.

My Service class is as follows:.

```
package com.example.a786computer1.mytryfyp;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyService extends Service {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

And i have created the service in my manifest as well, Pls help me regarding this!!

Comment: `startService method doesn't seem to appear anywhere` - Where would it appear? Are you clicking on button?

Comment: havent run the code yet, but the startservice(Intent view) isnt even being suggested by android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Fragment you need to call `getActivity().startService();`.

So replace,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MyService.class);
startService(intent);
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MyService.class);
getActivity().startService(intent);
```

Comment: thankyou for your kind feedback, code works just fine now :) happy coding brother!!